# Create Date that falls between 8 week period

Tags: mysql, postgresql

where I have to select the date range between 8 weeks.
One date is variable 'period_end_date_string' and other should change accordingly in query.

Can you suggest how it can be done,

```
select * from Dimension_Table where 
TELECAST_BROADCAST_DATE between '${parameters.period_end_date_string} - 
56' AND '${parameters.period_end_date_string}'

# period_end_date_string -sample '04/04/2019'
```

Comment: update your question and add  a data sample of your parameters.period_end_date_string content

Comment: mysql  or postgresql ????

Comment: which db you are really using ??''

Comment: ('01/01/2019', INTERVAL 8 WEEK) will work here?

Comment: [date and time functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html). Also note there is only one mysql date format and what you wrote isn't it.

Comment: Right Now I am using Netezza DB.

Comment: I got the answer.. thanks for support.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Solution :

select * from Dimension_Table where
TELECAST_BROADCAST_DATE between ('${parameters.period_end_date_string}'::date - interval '56 days') AND '${parameters.period_end_date_string}'

This is **('11/12/2019'::date - interval '56 days')** the syntax to get 56 days back date.